# AlarmManager vs wake up

Tags: android, alarmmanager, wakeup

This is my code:

Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

...

Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
    + (5 * 1000), pendingIntent);

...
}
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent service = new Intent(context, StartNotificationService.class);

    context.startService(service);
}
```

Service:

```
public class StartNotificationService extends Service {

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    this.intent = intent;
    showNotification();
}

private void showNotification() {
    Date date = new Date(pror.getFirstMillis());

    Log.i("date", date.toString());

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            createNotification(contentTitle, contentText, tickerText);

            pror.calculateVak();
            pror.setFirstMillis(pror.getNextVak());

            createStatusBarNotification(contentTitle, contentText, tickerText);
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask, date);
}

}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<application
     android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity android:name=".ShowSettingsActivity" />

    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"/> 
    <service android:name=".service.StartNotificationService"/>

    <activity android:name=".PreferencesActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
   </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".VakActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

When phone go to sleep, alarmManager can't start notification/service.

If I leave my phone in the 'active' - unlock state, a notification is triggered at a certain time.

Where I made mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to approach it.

1. If all you're doing is creating a status bar notification, then just do that in your `BroadcastReceiver`
2. If you need your service to run prior to making the notification, and you need this to be able to happen while device is asleep, you need to acquire a [`WAKE_LOCK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html)

So for approach **2** in your class body for the service you need:

```
PowerManager pm;
PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
```

Then in your `onCreate` you need:

```
pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
wl.acquire();
```

And then in your `onDestroy` you need to put:

```
wl.release();
```

All this info I got from [`PowerManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)

Comment: Actually, what you describe is insufficient. The device may well fall asleep between the end of `onReceive()` and the time you acquire the `WakeLock`. That's why I wrote the [`WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful), to have a reusable component that handles this pattern. That being said, I agree that the OP should just put the `Notification` in `onReceive()` and get rid of the `Service` and all the bizarre `TimerTask` stuff.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah, I guess that's true. If it were changed to [`getService`](http://goo.gl/cIK3g), and then OP used the `WakeLock` in `onCreate` of the service, that would work, correct?

Comment: Actually, that doesn't work either. Android does not guarantee that it will keep the device awake in that scenario. The only guarantee is *if* you use a `getBroadcast()` `PendingIntent`, *then* the device will stay awake long enough for `onReceive()` to complete. No other scenario has any wakefulness guarantee. Hence, you need to have overlapping `WakeLocks`, acquiring one in `onReceive()` before you return and Android releases its own. In essence, `WakefulIntentService` handles that overlapping `WakeLock` and related issues.

Comment: @CommonsWare. Can You write one example how can I do that?

Comment: @Kolesar: There is a `demo/` sub-project in the [`WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) project that demonstrates the use of `WakefulIntentService`. [Here is a free excerpt](http://commonsware.com/AdvAndroid/wakeful.pdf) from [one of my books](http://commonsware.com/AdvAndroid) that explains more about how `WakefulIntentService` works.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I've seen and implemented your code(from AdvAndroid-1.0-cc book), but I don't now how can I start an activity in the appservice class that device releases the wakelock after user's response to the activity?!